# Calculating cost of sales on mass SQL Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, insert

Using the following database as my source of data:

```
CREATE DATABASE [COS Source]
GO

USE [COS Source]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Products](
    [INVENTORY_CODE] [nvarchar](50),
    [PRODCAT_CODE] [nvarchar](50),
    [LAST_COST] [int] NULL,
    [STOCK_IND] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT piv PRIMARY KEY ([INVENTORY_CODE])
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Sales Header](
    [DOC_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50),
    [TRANSTYPE_CODE] [int] null ,
    [REP_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [TRANS_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [FIN_PERIOD] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT shdc PRIMARY KEY ([DOC_NUMBER])
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Sales Line](
    [DOC_NUMBER] [nvarchar](50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Sales Header]([DOC_NUMBER]),
    [INVENTORY_CODE] [nvarchar](50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products([INVENTORY_CODE]),
    [QUANTITY] [float] NULL,
    [UNIT_SELL_PRICE] [int] NULL,
    [TOTAL_LINE_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [LAST_COST] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT sldcic PRIMARY KEY ([DOC_NUMBER],[INVENTORY_CODE])
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Purchases Headers](
    [SUPPLIER_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PURCH_DOC_NO] [nvarchar](50),
    [PURCH_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT phpdn PRIMARY KEY ([PURCH_DOC_NO])
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Purchases Lines](
    [PURCH_DOC_NO] [nvarchar](50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Purchases Headers]([PURCH_DOC_NO]),
    [INVENTORY_CODE] [nvarchar](50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Products]([INVENTORY_CODE]),
    [QUANTITY] [float] NULL,
    [UNIT_COST_PRICE] [float] NULL,
    [TOTAL_LINE_COST] [float] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT plpdc PRIMARY KEY ([PURCH_DOC_NO],[INVENTORY_CODE])
) 
GO
```

And using the following database as my destination of the insert:

```
CREATE DATABASE [COS Target]
GO

USE [COS Target]
GO

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DIM (
    Product_Key int IDENTITY(1,1),  
    Product_Old_Key varchar(255),
    Unit_Sale_Price decimal,
    CONSTRAINT pk_PRODUCT_DIM PRIMARY KEY (Product_Key) 
)
GO

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT (
    Cust_Sales_Fact_Key int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Product_Key int,
    Cost_Of_Sales decimal,
    CONSTRAINT pk_CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT PRIMARY KEY (Cust_Sales_Fact_Key, Product_Key),
    CONSTRAINT Customer_Sale_Fact_Product_Key FOREIGN KEY (Product_Key) REFERENCES PRODUCT_DIM(Product_Key) ON DELETE CASCADE,
)
GO
```

I want to calculate the cost of sales (COS) for each `[COS Source].dbo.[Sales Line]` and insert this value into `[COS Target].dbo.[CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT].Cost_Of_Sales`. The basic formula to calculate the cost of sales per each sales line is: `[COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Lines].[QUANTITY] * [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Lines].[UNIT_COST_PRICE]`, or alternatively, just `[COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Lines].[TOTAL_LINE_COST]`.

The `[Product_Dim]` table is populated using the following query:

```
Insert into dbo.PRODUCT_DIM 
(
    Product_Old_Key
    ,[Unit_Sale_Price]
)
Select distinct p.INVENTORY_CODE ,p.LAST_COST from [COS Source].dbo.Products as p
Join [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Line] as sl
on p.INVENTORY_CODE = sl.INVENTORY_CODE
Join [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Header] sh
on sl.DOC_NUMBER = sh.DOC_NUMBER
GO
```

So far, the insert query which i have to populate `[COS Target].dbo.[CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT]`, but is not yet complete, is given bellow:

```
Insert into dbo.CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT
(     
      [Product_Key]     
      ,[Cost_Of_Sales]
)
Select Distinct targetProduct.Product_Key, null /*insert COS here*/from [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Line] as sl
Join [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Header] as sh
on sl.DOC_NUMBER = sh.DOC_NUMBER
Join [COS Source].dbo.Products as p
on p.INVENTORY_CODE = sl.INVENTORY_CODE
Join dbo.PRODUCT_DIM as targetProduct
on [COS Target].Product_Old_Key = p.INVENTORY_CODE
Join [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Lines] pl
on p.INVENTORY_CODE = pl.INVENTORY_CODE
Join [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Headers] as ph
on pl.PURCH_DOC_NO = ph.PURCH_DOC_NO
where ph.PURCH_DATE <= sh.TRANS_DATE
GO
```

Ideally I would like the calculated COS to be placed into the insert statement used to populate `[COS Target].dbo.[CUSTOMER_SALES_FACT]`, however the problem comes in where more than one purchase line exists for each product. Thus, in order to create an, at least partially, accurate COS, I must select a purchase line that has occured before the sales line. Meaning that the condition

```
WHERE [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Header].[TRANS_DATE] >=  [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Header].[PURCH_DATE]
```

is met.

I have not been successful in calculating and inserting the COS.

I am using SQL Server 2008. The tables also have money entries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece of information here is: for a given INVENTORY_CODE in a given sale (DOC_NUMBER), when was the most recent purchase containing this INVENTORY_CODE *previously* to the sale?

One option would be to create a helper view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[Most Recent Purchase] AS

SELECT sl.DOC_NUMBER, sl.INVENTORY_CODE, MAX(PURCH_DATE) LATEST_PURCH_DATE
FROM [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Lines] pl
JOIN [COS Source].dbo.[Purchases Headers] ph on pl.PURCH_DOC_NO=pl.PURCH_DOC_NO
JOIN [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Line] sl ON pl.INVENTORY_CODE = sl.INVENTORY_CODE 
JOIN [COS Source].dbo.[Sales Header] sh ON sh.DOC_NUMBER=sl.DOC_NUMBER
WHERE PURCH_DATE < sh.TRANS_DATE
GROUP BY sl.DOC_NUMBER, sl.INVENTORY_CODE
```

This view will now tell you for instance:

DOC_NUMBER  INVENTORY_CODE  LATEST_PURCH_DATE

1   123 2013-04-15

Sale 1 ( [Sales Header].DOC_NUMBER = 1) contains a sales line with INVENTORY_ID=123. The most recent purchase of an INVENTORY_ID=123 previously to this sale's TRANS_DATE was on 2013-04-15.

Now try adding this view to your join and take it from there.